# Remove except div with data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove divs except those with a data-id of 1. So far I have this:

```
$('#selection').on('change', function() {
    $selection = $(this).val();
    $("div[id*='showLangs']").remove();
}
```

Comment: yes I mean except

Comment: Where do you use `$selection = $(this).val();`? It would be better if you provide a working snippet that shows the problem you have. Please include the `HTML` too.

Comment: it would be better if you can provide a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more info, but i think you can try somethink like:

```
 $("div[id*='showLangs']:not([data-id='1'])").remove();
```

Or maybe, if you need to do some other staff with these that has the data-id attribute equal to 1.

```
$("div[id*='showLangs']").each(function(){
   if($(this).data('id') != 1){
      $(this).remove();
   }
   else {
     //do other stuf
   }
});
```